# Scala hashmap not getting appended

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I don't understand what is wrong with the code below. This works fine and `hashmap typeMap` gets updated if my input data frame is not partitioned. But if the code below is executed in a partitioned environment, `typeMap` is always empty and not updated. What is wrong with this code? Thanks for all your help.

```
var typeMap = new mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]
case class Combiner(,,,,,,,    mapTypes: mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]) {
    def execute() {
        <...>
        val combinersResult = dfInput.rdd.aggregate(combiners.toArray) (incrementCount, mergeCount)
    }

    def updateTypes(arr: Array[String], tempMapTypes:mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]): Unit = {
        <...>
        typeMap ++= tempMapTypes
    }

    def incrementCount(combiners: Array[Combiner], row: Row): Array[Combiner] = {
        for (i <- 0 until row.length) {
            val array = getMyType(row(i), tempMapTypes)
            combiners(i). updateTypes(array, tempMapTypes)
        }
        combiners
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there any clue?

Answer (score 2):

It is a really bad idea to use mutable values in distributed computing. With Spark in particular, `RDD` operations are shipped from the driver to the executors and are executed in parallel on all the different machines in the cluster. Updates made to your `mutable.HashMap` are never sent back to the driver, so you are stuck with the empty map that got constructed on the driver in the first place.

So you need to completely rethink your data structures by preferring immutability and to remember that operations firing on the executors are independent and parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I understood it now, but what would be the ideal way here to continue? I would need that updated map for further processing.

Comment: You don't need your maps to be mutable if you simply create new maps with values appended as you operate over your `RDD`, but if you must use a mutable map, at least initialize it inside your operation so each machine has its own copy.

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried that, updating the map in each partition and then use combine() to append the maps from all partitions, but that turned out to be a time consuming , is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: I read that accumulator can be used to send values from worker to drivers, In this scenario, how do I use them?